# How to get adjacency matrix from the graph in R?

Tags: r, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using pcalg package in R.

```
library(pcalg)
## Load predefined data
data(gmG)
## Define the score (BIC)
score <- new("GaussL0penObsScore", gmG8$x)
## Estimate the essential graph
ges.fit <- ges(score)

plot(ges.fit$essgraph)
```

I only know how to plot the graph. But I need the adjacency matrix from the ges.fit.

I need the adjacency matrix.

Comment: I don't know this package but isn't the adjacency matrix given by the last code line in `ges`'s example, `as(as(ges.fit$essgraph, "graphNEL"), "Matrix")`?

Comment: Also, package `"Rgraphviz"` isn't available for R 4.3.1, `install.packages` gives a `Warning message:
package ‘Rgraphviz’ is not available for this version of R`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, it's something from Bioconductor.